# Scale buttons in any resolution

Tags: c#, button, size, screen, scale

I'm trying to write a method that scales buttons in any resolution, on full screen without remaining space between them. Button parameters come from a web service. How can I resize them to fill all screen no matter what the parameters are. Or at least to scale their actual size to my new size. My form size is good but my buttons intersect.

```
   private void ResizeButtons()
   {
        pnlDynamicControls.Height = this.ClientSize.Height 
                                  - (pnlDynamicControls.Top + pnlButtons.Height);
        pnlDynamicControls.Width = pnlButtons.Width;
        float widthRatio = 
                    (float)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / ClientRectangle.Width;
        float heightRatio = 
                    (float)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / ClientRectangle.Height;
        SizeF scale = new SizeF(widthRatio,heightRatio);
        this.Scale(scale);

        //if ((widthRatio - pnlDynamicControls.Width) < (heightRatio - pnlDynamicControls.Height))
        //    l_zoomFactor = (float)widthRatio / pnlDynamicControls.Width;
        //else
        //    l_zoomFactor = (float)heightRatio / pnlDynamicControls.Height;

        foreach (Control c in pnlDynamicControls.Controls)
        {

            c.Height = Convert.ToInt16(c.Height * heightRatio);
            c.Width = Convert.ToInt16(c.Width * widthRatio);
            c.Margin = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 1);

            //c.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(
            //                                 Convert.ToInt16(c.Width * l_zoomFactor)
            //                               , Convert.ToInt16(c.Height * l_zoomFactor)
            //                                 );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the buttons in a FLP or where do you set their location?

Comment: Is this WinForms? If so, use the tag. You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` and `Dock=Fill`.

Comment: Thier location is set in a aspx and i receive it in JSON format.